# Download large file from server taking long time

Tags: java

I am trying to download the file(.mp4) from Kaltura and file is more than 100mb and below code is taking lot of time to download it.

Is there any other way to improve it ?

```
try {
        URL url = new URL("https://www.kaltura.com/p/....");
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        int n = 0;
        while (-1 != (n = in.read(buf)))
        {
            out.write(buf);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();     
        res.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=Smac_03_48.mp4 (iPad).mp4");
        res.setStatus(200);
        res.getOutputStream().write(out.toByteArray());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This question should really be posted to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I'm guessing the `ByteArrayOutputStream` doesn't expect that amount of data. Have you tried initializing it with a huge size, as you need it?

Comment: Yes I tried using huge size and it was taking the same as it was taking earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using below code and it's working fine as expected !

```
URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL(kalturaUrl);
    HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
        response.setContentType(httpConn.getContentType());
        response.setContentLength(httpConn.getContentLength());
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition"));
        OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

        int bytesRead = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } else {
        return "No file to download. Server replied HTTP code: " + httpConn.getResponseCode();
    }
    httpConn.disconnect();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    logger.error("Exception : ",e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.error("Exception : ",e);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that ByteArrayOutputStream will grow enormously, reallocating its size from time to time. Do instead an immediate output:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("https://www.kaltura.com/p/....");
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    res.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=Smac_03_48.mp4 (iPad).mp4");
    res.setStatus(200);
    OutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    int n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = in.read(buf)))
    {
        out.write(buf);
    }
    out.flush();
    in.close();     
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Of course a browser redirect would be even faster.